# Docker container port is not made public

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  apps:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    restart: always
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000

RUN npm install
RUN npm start
```

[image]

Only port expose is seen here but the internal port `3000` is not made public

[image]

**Versions:**

```
Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01
```

Comment: whats output when you try to access `http://localhost:3000` on host marchine ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan it returns nothing. https://i.imgur.com/FOdMwH0.png

Comment: The name of your container in the `docker ps` output isn't a standard Docker Compose name; did you actually run `docker-compose up` to start the container?

Comment: @DavidMaze you are right; the image wasn't created properly. I solved this after a change in the dockerfile; posted the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker image was not properly built since the last step to start node is defined incorrectly.

it is supposed to be like this,

```
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

[image]

Comment: I actually realized this, but first I preferred to see the logs. Anyway, I'm happy that your problem solved. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it! You used `docker-compose` and created `apps` service, but your container has a random name `crancky villani`!!!
go into the path your `docker-compose.yml` placed and run this command:

```sh
docker-compose down; docker-compose up -d --build
```

Then check the results again.

Comment: I tried this multiple times; no luck :( even removed the image and built manually

Comment: Which OS you are using? which version of `docker` and `docker-compose`?

Comment: Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01

Comment: my host machine is mac (mojave
)

Comment: When you run `docker-compose up --build` it will show you the steps of building your container. can you please send them here, so I can check the process? Please send the complete log.

Comment: I made a mistake in the Dockerfile last step `npm start`; which shouldn't be